# Value returns as 0

Tags: python

```
    bank = 0
    cash = 0

    userinput = input('would you like to work? ')

    if userinput == 'y':
        print('working...')
        newcash = 100
        newcash + cash
        print(cash)
```

When ever I run the program, it would return the cash value to 0.

Comment: Perhaps you  need to do `cash = newcash + cash` in place of `newcash + cash` ?

Comment: `newcash + cash` returns  a value that is never assigned to any variable. to change the value of `cash`, you need to assign the value to this variable, i.e., `cash = newcash + cash`

Answer (score 4):

`newcash + cash` is a result never assigned to anything. Try calling `cash += newcash` instead, or `cash = newcash + cash`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `newcash + cash`, you want to add the value of the variable `newcash` to the variable `cash` like so

```
cash = cash + newcash
```

or if you prefer a little "cleaner"

```
cash += newcash
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the variable cash is not updating when you doing addition (`newcash + cash`), returning 0 is correct answer for your current code.I think you want something like that :

```
bank = 0
cash = 0

userinput = input('would you like to work? ')
if userinput == 'y':
    print('working...')
    newcash = 100
    cash += newcash
    print(cash)
```

Now you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have to assign it like that:

```
cash = newcash + cash
```

instead of

```
newcash + cash
```